# to check and compare the null date of two or multiple tables

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi need help on how to query an output just like the result below:

external_id dev.repayment_date  prod.repayment_date
1234           2/1/21                  null
1234           2/16/21                 null
1234           null                    3/15/21
1234           null                    3/30/21

appreciate your answers on this. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to be more clear about source table (tables?), and the expected result you wish to obtain. What do you want to know from what data?

Answer (score 0):

With the current case description is hard to give you a proper answer, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
WITH data as (
SELECT 1234 as external_id, "2/1/21" as dev_repayment_date, null as prod_repayment_date UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, "2/16/21", null as prod_repayment_date UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, null, "3/15/21" as prod_repayment_date UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, null, "3/30/21" as prod_repayment_date UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, "2/16/21", "3/15/21" as prod_repayment_date 
)

, data_preparared as (SELECT 
  external_id, 
  PARSE_DATE("%x", dev_repayment_date) as dev_repayment_date,
  PARSE_DATE("%x", prod_repayment_date) as prod_repayment_date
FROM data)

SELECT 
  external_id, 
  dev_repayment_date > prod_repayment_date as date_comparison
FROM data_preparared 
WHERE 
  dev_repayment_date is not null 
  AND prod_repayment_date is not null
```

The first part (WITH statement) is creating the table called "data". The second part is the SELECT statement to query the "data". I parsed the dates.

If you need something more specific, please update the question accordingly.